# Why does my class not have a 'keys' function?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class a(object):
    w='www'
    def __init__(self):
        for i in self.keys():
            print i
    def __iter__(self):
            for k in self.keys():
                yield k

a() # why is there an error here?
```

Thanks.

---

Edit:  The following class also doesn't extend any class; 
why it can use `keys`?

```
class DictMixin:
    # Mixin defining all dictionary methods for classes that already have
    # a minimum dictionary interface including getitem, setitem, delitem,
    # and keys. Without knowledge of the subclass constructor, the mixin
    # does not define __init__() or copy().  In addition to the four base
    # methods, progressively more efficiency comes with defining
    # __contains__(), __iter__(), and iteritems().

    # second level definitions support higher levels
    def __iter__(self):
        for k in self.keys():
            yield k
    def has_key(self, key):
        try:
            value = self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return False
        return True
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return self.has_key(key)

    # third level takes advantage of second level definitions
    def iteritems(self):
        for k in self:
            yield (k, self[k])
    def iterkeys(self):
        return self.__iter__()

    # fourth level uses definitions from lower levels
    def itervalues(self):
        for _, v in self.iteritems():
            yield v
    def values(self):
        return [v for _, v in self.iteritems()]
    def items(self):
        return list(self.iteritems())
    def clear(self):
        for key in self.keys():
            del self[key]
    def setdefault(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            self[key] = default
        return default
    def pop(self, key, *args):
        if len(args) > 1:
            raise TypeError, "pop expected at most 2 arguments, got "\
                              + repr(1 + len(args))
        try:
            value = self[key]
        except KeyError:
            if args:
                return args[0]
            raise
        del self[key]
        return value
    def popitem(self):
        try:
            k, v = self.iteritems().next()
        except StopIteration:
            raise KeyError, 'container is empty'
        del self[k]
        return (k, v)
    def update(self, other=None, **kwargs):
        # Make progressively weaker assumptions about "other"
        if other is None:
            pass
        elif hasattr(other, 'iteritems'):  # iteritems saves memory and lookups
            for k, v in other.iteritems():
                self[k] = v
        elif hasattr(other, 'keys'):
            for k in other.keys():
                self[k] = other[k]
        else:
            for k, v in other:
                self[k] = v
        if kwargs:
            self.update(kwargs)
    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(dict(self.iteritems()))
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return 1
        if isinstance(other, DictMixin):
            other = dict(other.iteritems())
        return cmp(dict(self.iteritems()), other)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.keys())
```

Comment: `class A(object):`, per PEP 8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I have added a note on iterating over attributes of an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you expect it to have `keys`? You didn't define such a method in your class. Did you intend to inherit from a dictionary?

To do that declare class `a(dict)`

Or maybe you meant `a.__dict__.keys()`?

As for the large snippet you've posted in the update, read the comment above the class again:

```
 # Mixin defining all dictionary methods for classes that already have
 # a minimum dictionary interface including getitem, setitem, delitem,
 # and keys
```

Note that "**already have ... keys**" part.

The `DictMixin` class comes from the `UserDict` module, which says:

> class UserDict.DictMixin  Mixin
>   defining all dictionary methods for
>   classes that already have a minimum
>   dictionary interface including
>   **getitem**(), **setitem**(), **delitem**(), and keys().
>
> This mixin should be used as a
>   superclass. Adding each of the above
>   methods adds progressively more
>   functionality. For instance, defining
>   all but **delitem**() will preclude
>   only pop() and popitem() from the full
>   interface.
>
> In addition to the four base methods,
>   progressively more efficiency comes
>   with defining **contains**(),
>   **iter**(), and iteritems().
>
> Since the mixin has no knowledge of
>   the subclass constructor, it does not
>   define **init**() or copy().
>
> Starting with Python version 2.6, it
>   is recommended to use
>   collections.MutableMapping instead of
>   DictMixin.

Note the recommendation in the last part - use `collections.MutableMapping` instead.

To iterate over attributes of an object:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myinstatt1 = 'one'
        self.myinstatt2 = 'two'
    def mymethod(self):
        pass

a = A()
for attr, value in a.__dict__.iteritems():
    print attr, value
```

Comment: Two seconds work with Google found http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/08/17/dictmixin/, http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html, and http://snipplr.com/view/6546/creating-dictionarylike-objects-in-python-using-dictmixin/, all of which explain how to use DictMixin - and that was knowing no more than the name. I'm sure baidu could have found those sites for you just as easily.